# Does Visual Studio 2019's Quick find in file (Ctrl + F) display count and index of occurrences anywhere?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When searching a string in a file in Visual Studio, I press Ctrl+F. I noticed that when I search a string, there is no indication that I can find on the screen that tells me the total count of matches in the file, and the index of the currently focused match. (i.e 3 of 5)

Is this an option, or is it somewhere I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You get that if you use the "big" search box (Press `CTRL+SHIFT+F` or click on the folder-with-magnifying-glass icon in the toolbar). If you use that to search, you get a summary as well (and you can search multiple files at once)

Comment: Ctrl + F is more convenient in a single file and yeah would be really nice to have a total count and position there

Comment: @Izzy I agree that it would be convenient, but at least it works using the big search box. You can set it to search the current file only, as well.

Comment: I understand that it's doable (the entire CTRL+F on the file is doable as well in the big search box but there's a reason that they made the CTRL+F for the file) and all I'm saying is that it would be great if it would be included in the CTRL+F